# Are we at risk from account hackers and is there any cause for concern?

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts

I was wondering if there is a history of account hacking on the SE network; and, if my account were to be hacked for any reason, what are the implications and would there be help at hand for this occasion. (say in the instance of account ban or loss of rep)

It just occurred to me because although there seems to be little point at all to hack a member's SE account. (except from maybe gaining Moderator rights or the like) but you know the internet as well as I do and people do it for the sheer fun of it. what are the risks involved?

Comment: Your **Open ID** account (Facebook, Google, Yahoo, Stack Exchange, whichever ones you are using) would have to be hacked. I have not seen any genuine reports of anyone being hacked.

Comment: And your Facebook or Google account holds far more valuable info than your access to Stack Exchange sites, so I'd say 'nope, no reason for concern'.

Comment: There have been cases where people have left themselves logged in to public computers. In those cases the we can log the user out everywhere and invalidate cookies.

Comment: Ah cool. I just thought I'd ask because it didn't seem to be discussed anywhere.